# Does the Torque Bow have lethal splash damage?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

In Gears of War 4 (or any Gears for that matter),  the Torque Bow shoots an explosive bolt.  Can you kill someone with a single shot if you shoot the ground or wall they are near with the splash damage? I know you can get multi-kills with it if you stick someone and they walk next to one of their teammates, but I've never been able to get a kill with splash damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I have done this multiple times by shooting the Torque Bow Bolt at the ground right next to the enemy as I knew they were hiding around the corner (as I didn't have a direct shot) and I was able to kill them with splash damage.  It is possible, but rather difficult as the splash radius is rather small.  If you don't kill them, you will hurt them.

I can try to do a game capture of this and post it here, but it might be a little bit before I can complete that request (later tonight).

Comment: That game clip would be nice to see. I have today actually witnessed someone get a kill with the splash, though the person they killed was weakened by some bullets first.

Comment: @TimmyJim http://www.trueachievements.com/gameclip.aspx?clipid=58587904    At around :22 seconds in, but not sure if that person took dmg before.